# Writing Angular Unit test for Nested rest Get Calls

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am writing a funtion in Angular which is inheriting getSingle suntion of some other Service file, two times, when i am writing the Unit test , it says, getSingle already spied upon. Please help me with the Unit test.

```
getSingle<T>(id: string, unit: string): Observable<T> {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      const getCustSub: Subscription = super.getSingle(id, 'test').subscribe(
        (items: any) => {
          const id = items?.test.cId;
          if (id) {
            const getPerSub: Subscription = super.getSingle(id, 'testing').subscribe(
              (response: any) => {
                const name = response.user.name;
                const uid = response.user.id;
                items.test = { ...items.test, user: { name, id, uid } };
                this.removeSubscriptions();
                observer.next(items);
              },
              () => {
                this.removeSubscriptions();
                observer.next(items);
              }
            );
            this.subscription.add(getPerSub);
          } else {
            this.removeSubscriptions();
            observer.next(items);
          }
        },
        (errOfGetCustomer: any) => {
          this.removeSubscriptions();
          observer.error(errOfGetCustomer);
        }
      );
      this.subscription.add(getCustSub);
    });
  }
```

Comment: The error message suggests an error in your unit test, so show that.